# Change animator state of inactive gameobject unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a switch for dark/light theme, the switch deafults to on, which is what i want but it's a child of an inactive gameobject (hidden in settings). I save the theme data with `PlayerPrefs.SetString("theme", "light")`. What I want is to have the switch default to off state when the "theme" is set to light and default to on state when "theme" is set to dark.

I also made sure I'm calling setThemeOnStart in the `void Awake(){}`

This is my code that I tried
"themebutt" is the animator

```
private void setThemeOnStart()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("theme") != "light") return;
        //Change dark theme boolean so the code knows it's already in light theme
        isDark = false;
        //try to change to "switch-off" state
        themebutt.Play("switch-off");
    }
```

Edit:
The script isn't attached to the inactive object.

Comment: Awake will not run if the object with the script is not enabled.

Comment: if it is only about enabling and disabling the object why not simply `themebutt.SetActive` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to Play, the animator must be active and enabled.
I suggest putting animator on active parent object and "themebutt" inside of it. Animation that plays on parent can freely enable/disable "themebutt" and do anything with its children.

Hint: to edit your animation to different objects you can select object and press F2 in order to change its parents just add "parent/" to its path, like shown on the picture.[image]